# Images not showing until scroll with Lazy Load plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, lazy-loading

I'm developing a phonegap app and I'm using the Lazy Load plugin (http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload).

The problem I have is that images do not show until the user scrolls. I have a demo [here](http://www.test.webintelligence.ie/). If you click on CauseComprehensiveSchoolGallery, you can see that images don't become visibile until you scroll. I have looked at this SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13535597/lazyload-images-not-appearing-until-after-a-scroll) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13971151/jquery-lazyload-do-not-load-images-until-scroll) and tried all the solutions, but none have worked.

The image tags look like this:

```
<img class="lazy" data-original="<%= item.thumbnail %>" height="70" width="70" >
```

and the javscript is:

```
$('img.lazy').lazyload();
```

As you can see, the height and width are sets, which is the usual solution put forward. I also tried:

```
$("img.lazy").lazyload({
    skip_invisible : false
});
```

and

```
 $(window).resize();
```

and, to simulate a scroll

```
 $('body').scrollTop(10);
```

But again, the images still don't show until i scroll. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to solve the issue:

1. Trigger "scroll" event manually to force lazyload script to load images:

   ```
   $(window).trigger('scroll');
   ```
2. Use another lazy-loading script (e.g. [jQuery LazyLoadXT](http://ressio.github.io/lazy-load-xt/)) that works correctly.

   -- If using this plugin, make sure to include the plugin ***and*** to initialize the Horizontal Scrolling function by passing the "horizontal scrolling overflow container" to lazyLoadXT

   -- (eg, container of items ".wrapper") like so: [$.lazyLoadXT.scrollContainer = '.wrapper';](https://github.com/ressio/lazy-load-xt/blob/master/README.md#horizontal-scroll)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but mine was fixed by adding skip_invisible: false to the options (was not there previously). I'm adding this answer here although I'm actually voting for the other answer because I think it is more thorough.