# calculate scrolltop on infinity scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax function that gets more posts.

But I would like to trigger it automatically.

My html structure looks like this

```
<div class="header">
    ....
</div>
<ul id="grid">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <!-- load more content -->
</ul>
<div>
    ....
</div>
<div>
    ....
</div>
<div>
    ....
</div>
<div>
    ....
</div>
<div class="footer">
    ....
</div>
```

I'm using this code right now.

```
var count = 2;
    $(window).scroll(function(){
            if  ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
               loadArticle(count);
               count++;
            }
    });
```

That code trigger ajax function only when the user reach bottom of the page.

Can anyone tell me the proper way to calculate scrolltop?

Comment: CHeck this SO, i beleive this is what u need,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118075/lazyload-plugin

Comment: @dreamweiver not really. My ajax loading working fine. But its not triggering at the correct position

Comment: Could you please create a jsfiddle so that we can check the issue, http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: could you tell me when does the loading of the more items trigger, because i didnt notice that in your page

Comment: @dreamweiver While page loading you can see only 12 products. But when you scroll to the bottom of that page ajax will be triggered and it will load more products

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43820/discussion-between-dreamweiver-and-giri)

Comment: @dreamweiver Dude, I used alternate method. I posted my answer. Thanks for your time.

Comment: oh good, what did you do ? try posting that as a answer and close this Question, may be someone in future may be in need of the same

Comment: @dreamweiver Check my answer. Scrolldown

Answer (score 1):

Use following code

```
function bindScroll(){

  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $("#grid").height() - $(window).height() - 10) {

    // unbind scroll
    $(window).unbind('scroll');

    //call ajax function 
    loadArticle(count);

  }
}

function loadArticle(count){
   ....
   ..Ajax Call ..
   ....
   //bind sroll again
   bindScroll();
}
```

and call **bindScroll()** function in **$(document).ready** section to bind scroll event

Answer (score 0):

Ok I used some alternate solution.

I hope it will be useful for others.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  
var count = 2;
$.log(count);
var total = <?php echo $wp_query->max_num_pages; ?>;
            $(window).scroll(function(){
                    if (element_in_scroll("#inifiniteLoader")) {
                       if (count > total){
                            $("#inifiniteLoader").css('display','none');  
                            return false;  
                        }else{
                            $("#inifiniteLoader").css('display','block');  
                            loadArticle(count);  
                        }  
                       count++;
                    }
            }); 
function loadArticle(pageNumber) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php bloginfo('wpurl') ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        type:'POST',
        data: "action=infinite_scroll&page_no="+ pageNumber, 
        success: function(html){
            $("#og-grid").append(html);    // This will be the div where our content will be loaded
        }
    });
    return false;
}
function element_in_scroll(elem)
{
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();
    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}
});
</script>


#inifiniteLoader {
    margin: 20px 0;
    display:none;
}
```

Place this code where you want the loading image.

```
<div style="text-align:center;" class="clear" id="inifiniteLoader">
    <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/img/loading.gif">
</div>
```

For loading image [check here](https://www.google.com/search?q=loading%20gif&safe=off&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=lnt&tbs=isz%3ai)

Comment: Cool, try closing this Question by ticking it as answer.

Comment: @dreamweiver Actually I need to wait 2 days to accept my own answer

Comment: yeah i can understand, no probs, juts remember to do so.

Comment: @dreamweiver yep.. I will accept it. Again Thanks for your time